# How to configure doxyfile and get documentation for .doc file as input to generate html output in Doxygen?

Tags: documentation, doxygen, documentation-generation, doxygen-wizard, doxygen-addtogroup

I have a task of documenting a file with extension .doc using doxygen tool. I am able to generate html output for a .cpp file but stuck to set the correct configuration of doxyfile to generate html output for file with .doc extension as input file .Please help me out to solve this problem.

Comment: What is the format of the doc file, how does it look like? Which version of doxygen are you using? Did you have a look a the settings like `FILE_PATTERN`, `EXTENSION_MAPPING`, `INPUT`, `RECURSIVE`?

Comment: The doc file contains plain text without being commented I want to get a html output for that plain text.For that I need to configure doxyfile with input .doc file extension.I have gone through the settings for FILE_PATTERN, EXTENSION_MAPPING,INPUT, RECURSIVE...BUT NOT ABLE to configure the doxyfile for .doc extension.Please help me out.

Comment: Maybe the following will start you `FILE_PATTERNS += *.doc`
`EXTENSION_MAPPING  = doc=md`

Comment: It is not necessary to make "comments" out of the test in your .doc file, but you have to  set both settings as indicated. Do you get any warnings? Can you see in your console output that the .doc file is mentioned? Which version of doxygen ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above mentioned to document a doc file but it failed should Is it necessary to comment the contents in doc file to get html output or it's ok if we just parse the file by mentioning FILE_PATTERNS =*.doc

Comment: Your answer is not an answer but just showing that you have a problem, should be added to the original question (edited in) or added as a comment.

Comment: Which version of Doxygen is the best to get html output for plain text file with .doc extension?

Comment: The latest doxygen version (and also look at the setting `EXTENSION_MAPPING`)